# SQL - Set field as count from another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to set a field in my target table as the count of the email addresses in another table. An email address can appear many times in my other table and I wanted to count the total up and set that count as my target field value.

```
SELECT 
  a.*
 ,a.PickedUp_Count AS COUNT(b.Emailaddress)
FROM 
  Master_List a
INNER JOIN 
  Picked_Up b
    ON 
      a.Emailaddress = b.Emailaddress
```

Comment: For future reference people are more likely to help you if you format your code so it is easy to read.

Comment: Would it be `COUNT(b.Emailaddress) AS PickedUp_Count`, instead ..?

Comment: No, he'd also be missing the group by statement.  You need to complete aggregate for all the columns.

Comment: I think we need a little more to go on here. Table schemas, at least. Sample data would help a lot, too. Here are some suggested tools. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Gerik yes,you're right, the sql also needs complete aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best not to use * selectors because usually you want to know specifically what you're getting back from a table.  You don't have to expand it in the select, but you DO have to identify how all of the individual columns will also be aggregated in the group by column.

```
SELECT 
     a.<field1>
     a.<field2>
    ....
    ,COUNT(*) as PickedUp_Count
FROM 
    Master_List a 
    INNER JOIN Picked_Up b 
        ON a.Emailaddress = b.Emailaddress
GROUP BY
    <field1>
   ,<field2>
   ....
```

The group by must include all fields listed in the select which are not already being aggregated in the select - i.e. any field that isn't the count.

Additionally, it's worth noting that PickedUp_Count is whatever random name you choose.

Comment: Yeah, * are good for casual SQL when looking around tables. When preparing the real SQL that will be run by your app, it's better to stay away from *.